# Good C IDE for Mac?

Tags: c, macos, ide

I've just started a job where I'm programming in C on a Mac, which is my first experience using a Mac for development. For now I'm using Xcode as my editor, then using make/gcc/svn at the command line for compiling and source control.

Is there a good, full featured IDE out there for Macs that will compile C code (something comparable to VS would be ideal), or should I stick with these low level tools?

EDIT: so I called Xcode a "low level tool" because I was under the impression that it was just a text editor for code, like gvim. I will definitely look into it's compiling/source control features.

Comment: Weird... why are you leaving Xcode to compile and version control?
Xcode has subversion and CVS support built in. It also compiles using a version of gcc.

Comment: I'd suggest using vim, but I don't want to get shot. :)

Comment: I would actually love to be able to somehow use vim 'in' xcode ... xcode is otherwise perfect and I'm slowly learning shortcuts to get around - but I would still be faster with vim ... apart from jumping to api headers, switching between .h/.m which is awesome ... and so on

Comment: @stefanB I agree, and aside from just vim controls I wish I could import my favorite ".vimrc" file. I've played with the text editing preferences but they seemed to be lacking.

Comment: Be sure to check out https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/ Clion by jetbrains!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can also try [Eclipse with the CDT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).

Comment: +1 for eclipse CDT, really like it.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse with CDT is quite nice. You will also get the task focused UI (Mylin) which is now included in all Eclipse downloads. It helps a lot when connected to a bugtracking system

Comment: NetBeans is another good Java-based IDE that supports C/C++.

Answer (score 9):

Good ide: **Xcode**

Good non-ide option: **vim/make/gcc**

Comment: CodeRunnerApp also live to its standards. https://coderunnerapp.com/

Answer (score 8):

[textmate](/questions/tagged/textmate) - [Download from Macromates website.](http://macromates.com/download)

The latest version is [textmate2](/questions/tagged/textmate2) but some people choose to keep using [textmate-1.5](/questions/tagged/textmate-1.5) because there are significant differences between the two versions and they're both **awesome**.

Comment: this will return: False

Comment: Spiritwalker, Relevant: http://i55.tinypic.com/kdmvz9.jpg

Comment: haha, you got a good sense of humor. i don't hate textmate, i loved it when i used to use it. but once i tried other editors, especially vim, my mind about textmate has changed. another reason it's not awesome is that the update (v. 2) is not coming for how many years i don't know.

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled over [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator).  It seems to hold up really nice where every other IDE failed me when working with a plain Makefile project.

XCode, Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans wouldn't resolve dependencies, or load my project in a good way. In Qt Creator I could just point to *New Project » Import Project » Import Existing Project* and voila!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Objective-C is a superset of C (a pretty pure one, if I recall correctly). You should be able to use XCode for editing, compiling, and debugging.

Here's one solution (which tells you to create a C++ project, then rename main.cpp to main.c)... http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~s70201/C_In_Xcode/Xcode_Tutorial.html

Comment: especially as xcode has built-in SVN support, and can easily use an external makefile for building

Answer (score 1):

Xcode can manage project and compile for you as any IDE. But if you're familiar with CLI, I would recommand you to use a good editor and your usual build tools. Emacs and vim are available on os x (using xcode just for its editor is not ideal). Many mac dev love the excellent TextMate editor, but it is not a free (as in freedom) software.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously 'good' is a subjective decision, but Xcode 3.2 is certainly up to par with what you can do in VisualStudio (if one considers VS good, is another thing of course).

I have a project with 250000+ lines of codes, 10 dylibs, helpfile, all in an SVN (Perforce) etc. and hardly ever go outside Xcode.

Xcode has a few peculiar ways to do some things and the debugger is not quite as powerful as the current one in VisualStudio, but overall there's hardly anything you can not do from within the IDE (and the options to adjust the shortcuts within the IDE, Debugger and Editor to your needs are really awesome).