# what else text editors can be used to editor Objective-C code except xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, ide

I am new to mac, my question is what else text editors can be used to edit Objective-C code except xcode. And which one is the best for productively editing source code?

Comment: Relevant: [Good C IDE for Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739517/good-c-ide-for-mac)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [TextMate](http://macromates.com/)?

Comment: I just bought a macbook, and didn't try textmate yet:)

Comment: Download the trial, I'm sure you wont be disappointed. It has support for several other languages as well(ruby, python, javascript). May I ask why you want some other editor than xcode for objective-c?

Comment: I recommend TextMate too. It's pretty much the standard programmer's editor on the Mac, and it works fine with ObjC (and unlike Xcode, it can open multiple files in tabs ;).

Comment: I think it's not very good for navigation and typing in Xcode, so I want to know if I can try some other editors. I already tried textmate, it's really great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What text editors can't edit c code?

I'd recommend vim, emacs or textmate.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs, obviously, tho' heretics will advise Vi(m).

Comment: vi(m) obviously, though the heretics will advise emacs.